# Can't get my Blue Snowflake Mic to work

Tags: hardware, usb, microphone

It was working fine when I bought it. I think it was an update or something that made it stop. I don't think the Mic is broken, at least I hope not. Can anyone help?

Please? I need it before tommorrow. I'm working on a video.

I get this when I check the terminal for what USB devices are connected:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2525:8912
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:00d2 Wacom Co., Ltd
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you could add some logs to your question it would help. See this question for log details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Okay, so I remember it working fine around 10.04 then I stopped using the Microphone and upgraded to 10.10 and now the computer doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I tested it on a Windows computer and it said it couldn't recognize it either, do you think it's the microphone?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you unsuccessfully tried it on your windows pc, did you install the drivers for it? If it didn't work on windows with the official drivers, then you have a hardware problem. Could be:

- your usb port or hub is broken
- the mic is broken

Doesn't bode well that it doesn't detect the device with a name.